# Android studio: Sdk Emulator: VCRUNTIME1400.dll can't be found

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, windows-10

**[WINDOWS 10]

Sdk not working: I'm out of solutions**

So I installed Android Studio not long ago.
I installed everything right, I installed in the sdk tools :

- Android Emulator
- Android DSK platform tools
- Intel (x86) Emulator accelerator (HAXM)

I installed the API-Level 30 (x86 too)
I tried enabling/disabling launching in a tool window
I uninstalled and reinstalled everything several time

Next, I tried launching the emulator with command line
I first created an AVD: Pixel_XL_API_30 and used the command
`emulator.exe -avd Pixel_XL_API_30` in the right folder with admin and non-admin privileges
I get a VCRUNTIME140.dll not found

So I tried fixing the dll following mainly (https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-fix-the-vcruntime140dll-is-missing-error-on-windows-10)
I ran scannow, I tried repair tools in all Visual studio version I could find in apps and functionalities
Then I tried unrergistering and registering back the dll and I get the following :

`Module VCRUNTIME140.dll was loaded but entry point dllRegisterServer not found` (more or less)
Same for dllUnregisterServer.

And here I am stuck and desperately in need of your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I reinstalled Microsoft Visual C++ 2015, 2017 and 2019 redistributable (in x64  (I've mistakenly downloaded the x86 at first) and now it works

(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0)